# Fit to landscape longtable generated with xtable and sweave

Tags: tables, longtable, sweave, width

I read many TEX questions/answers on fitting a table to your page width, but cannot figure out how to do apply it in my context (using xtable/sweave). Everything that I tried (using adjustbox, tabu) have not worked yet. I have a pretty bad overfull \hbox (262.58336pt too wide) in alignment at lines 18--41.

Here's my code and [Rdata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fn2ekxiyw4m66w8/Table_wratio_scaled_elasmo_nospatialtemporal.Rdata):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=F>>=
load("Table_wratio_scaled_elasmo_nospatialtemporal.Rdata")
require(xtable)
finalx <- xtable(final2,label="bigtable",caption="List of ...")
@


\begin{landscape}
<<Final table, echo=F,results=tex>>=
print(finalx,tabular.environment="longtable", caption.placement="top",
        size="\\small", table.placement="", floating=FALSE)
@
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Here's how the xtable output looks like:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Thu Oct 17 08:53:16 2013
{\small
\begin{longtable}{rlrrrrrrrrrrr}
\caption{List of all fishery and mean weight (mt) of elasmobranch category captured in observed Canadian fisheries} \\ 
  \hline
 & fishery & Obs\_tspp & Obs\_Selachii & Obs\_Batoid & wratio\_Selachii & wratio\_Batoid & Obs\_Sets & log\_tspp & scaled\_Selachii & scaled\_Batoid & Obs\_proxie & scaled\_Elasmo \\ 
  \hline
1 & Total & 118025.04 & 390.78 & 493.10 &  &  & 37270.00 & 670446.67 & 3425.09 & 3273.37 &  & 6698.46 \\ 
  2 & SWORDFISH-Line & 84.85 & 81.00 & 0.07 & 0.96 & 0.97 & 62.00 & 919.91 & 892.72 & 0.62 & 9.22 & 893.34 \\ 
  3 & HALIBUT(ATL)-Line & 261.41 & 17.80 & 66.86 & 0.07 & 0.07 & 953.00 & 1793.35 & 126.37 & 498.40 & 14.58 & 624.77 \\ 
  4 & COD(ATL)-Line & 398.41 & 8.51 & 24.58 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 616.00 & 6360.91 & 130.13 & 394.79 & 6.26 & 524.92 \\ 

....

58 & CUSK-Line & 2.11 & 0.04 & 0.17 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 16.00 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\label{bigtable}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: is it possible to show the effective latex document for those of us without sweave set up. In particular what is the longtable argument `\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data fits easily on the page, but your headings don't so you need to re-word them or rotate them or shorten them.

This fits for example, but may not be what you want:

```
 & \rotatebox{90}{fishery} & \rotatebox{90}{Obs\_tspp} & \rotatebox{90}{Obs\_Selachii} & \rotatebox{90}{Obs\_Batoid} & \rotatebox{90}{wratio\_Selachii} & \rotatebox{90}{wratio\_Batoid} & \rotatebox{90}{Obs\_Sets} & \rotatebox{90}{log\_tspp} & \rotatebox{90}{scaled\_Selachii} & \rotatebox{90}{scaled\_Batoid} & \rotatebox{90}{Obs\_proxie} & \rotatebox{90}{scaled\_Elasmo} \\
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle, the problem with this command is that I cannot use with xtable/sweave. I guess I have to manipulate somehow the display of my column within xtable or as you suggested change my headings for something shorter. Should I post this question on stackoverflow since now it seems more of a xtable/R coding rather than a LaTex issue? Thank you!

Comment: @GodinA can you not put the `\rotatebox{}{long title}` into sweave where you previously just put `long title` ? As you say if that's hard, it isn't really a TeX question anymore

Comment: @Godina actually you can do this sort of things with xtables, see the gallery/vignette, section 4.7. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Could have also done

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaystable}
INSERT TABLE
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by extending it to show a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that the OP and future visitors can compile for testing purposes. For example, for this code to be successful, both the `pdflscape` and `rotating` packages are required. This is critical information for anyone hoping to use this solution.

Comment: -1.  Answers on this site are usually self-contained, such that people can simply copy-paste the document and compile.  This is not the case in this answer and it is therefore not useful.